# Farseer physics Engine 3.1 with Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0, farseer

When I try to reference the project of farseer with a WP7 game targeted to mango, it gives an error about these projects being different in "refresh levels"

The integration with a NoDo Game works fine.

How should I solve this? I don't want end up creating a NoDo Game...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just got an answer from Farseer's fan page administrator, they're working on releasing a version specifically for mango and also working on making video tutorials for the engine...

Answer (score 0):

Download Farseer source code from [their site](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/) and compile it by yourself. I'm pretty sure the assembly versions have changed from NoDo to Mango.

Answer (score 0):

After compiling the source code, add reference to farseer dll file (not to the project).

Answer (score 0):

Since Farseer's main download still has not been updated for Mango (A little concerning that the project seems to have stagnated)-- if anyone finds this question, I believe the simplest fix for this issue is just to right click the Farseer Physics project in the Solution Explorer and select "Upgrade Windows Phone Projects". This allows the reference to be made and doesn't raise any errors for me. I've yet to see if the functionality of the engine remains intact, but wouldn't imagine anything would go terribly wrong.